# I'm getting "mention not defined" error when trying to pass v12 code to v13

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to pass a code from v12 to v13 and I get "mention not defined" error. I think it might be in that part bellow. Could someone tell me if this is on v13?

```
message.channel.send({content: `${mention === "@everyone" ? "`@everyone`" : `${mention === undefined ? '' : '`@' +mention.name+ '`'}`}`, embeds: [previewEmbed] }).then(delMsg => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            delMsg.delete()
          }, 60000)
        })


      })

  })
```

Comment: You should include any error messages in full as text. Why do you think this code is fault? [Edit] the question and tell us what you want to do, show what you tried, and show the results.

Comment: If I mention everyone or any role it sends perfectly, but if I don't mention any role the bot sends the message, but it appears above the embed "Undefined". There is no error in the terminal, only this problem that I mentioned above.
When I put console.log(mention) it says "mention is not defined" so I think the problem is in this part of the code, but maybe it's in another part, I'm not sure.

Comment: [edit] the question and make sure all the details are there for people to read. Comments are not part of the Q&A.